# Error accessing specific value from JSON file

Tags: python, json, string, integer, typeerror

I'm trying to parse some JSON, and I need to extract certain values and store them in a 2D list.  However when I try to save a single value I keep getting an TypeError.  Also I am using Python 3.6.8.

I have tried to look at a couple different solutions, like casting it as a list, integer and string.  I also have looked at the following links: [attempt1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855276/parsing-json-with-python-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-str/25855320) , [attempt2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723615/python-json-parse-to-list) and [attempt3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659968/accessing-specific-json-value).  I believe the error is coming from how I am attempting to access the value.  I have tried to play around with my code to get it to run properly but I just cannot get it to execute.

This is my code:

```
with open('../data.json') as json_data:
    j = json.load(json_data)
    json_data.close()

for chat in range(len(j["data"]["chats"])):
    temp = []
    for msg in range(len(j["data"]["chats"][chat]["messages"])):
        item = j[["data"]["chats"][chat]["messages"][msg]["sender"]["id"]]
        print(item)
```

This is some of my JSON:

```
{  
    "application":"HelloWorld",
    "data":{  
       "chats":[  
          {  
             "name":"max",
             "parties":[  
                {  
                   "id":"1"
                },
                {  
                   "id":"2"
                }
             ],
             "messages":[  
                {  
                   "sender":{  
                      "id":"1"
                   },
                   "id":"1234",
                   "content":[  
                      {  
                         "data":"Hello number 2",
                         "type":"txt"
                      }
                   ],
                   "timestamp":{  
                      "created":816080400
                   }
                },
```

The chat section repeats 4 times, the message item repeats a couple times in each chat, and then the sender item repeats a couple times in each message item.

Currently my code just shoots out an error at the line:

```
item = j[["data"]["chats"][chat]["messages"][msg]["sender"]["id"]]
```

The Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    item = j[["data"]["chats"][chat]["messages"][msg]["sender"]["id"]]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What I would like to do is successfully print the value so the following happens:

```
print(item)
#Will print:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why do you use `len()` for iteration if it is not required this code will give you what you want, where `app` variable is your json

```
for chat in app['data']['chats']:
    for msg in chat['messages']:
        item = msg['sender']['id']
        print(item)
```

UPD1: Your version looks like that:

```
j[["data"]["chats"][chat]["messages"][msg]["sender"]["id"]]
j["data"]["chats"][chat]['messages'][msg]['sender']['id']
```

As you can see - there is `[]` near j variable

Comment: Ahh I now see my error with my old code, thanks for the update!  I ended up using your code.  Must easier to follow, thanks.